# Create Leap Motion Java Application (including -Djava.library.path inside jar)

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, leap-motion

I am developing in Java an Leap Motion Application with IntelliJ.

My developing finished and it works to compile in my IDE. After I found out, 
how to create an JAR with all my dependencies. (LeapMotion.jar, processing/core.jar), I don't know how to use Native Libs, like C++, in my Jar.

The Leap Motion SDK is written in C++.
IntelliJ is linked via `-Djava.library.path` to use the C++ files. 
For my System (Ubuntu 13.10) I need the .so files to run my program. 
How can I compile a Jar by including the C++ file, to run the application without IntelliJ?

[image]